# How do you specifiy a nonlinearity parameter when using FastICA algorithm in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, parameters

I have downloaded and successfully installed the [MATLAB FastICA package](http://research.ics.aalto.fi/ica/fastica/).

The main algorithm is implemented in [fastica.m](https://github.com/probml/pmtksupport/blob/master/fastICA-2.5/fastica.m)

The author has generously provided sample demo code which I was able to successfully run shown below:

```
N=500; %data size

v=[0:N-1];

sig(1,:)=sin(v/2); %sinusoid
sig(2,:)=((rem(v,23)-11)/9).^5; %funny curve
sig(3,:)=((rem(v,27)-13)/9); %saw-tooth
sig(4,:)=((rand(1,N)<.5)*2-1).*log(rand(1,N)); %impulsive noise

%create mixtures

Aorig=rand(size(sig,1));
mixedsig=(Aorig*sig);

%preform ica to unmix signal
ica = fastica(mixedsig);

subplot(2,4,1); plot(sig(1,:));
title('1')
subplot(2,4,2); plot(sig(2,:));
title('2')
subplot(2,4,3); plot(sig(3,:));
title('3')
subplot(2,4,4); plot(sig(4,:));
title('4')
subplot(2,4,5); plot(ica(3,:));
title('5')
subplot(2,4,6); plot(ica(1,:));
title('6')
subplot(2,4,7); plot(ica(2,:));
title('7')
subplot(2,4,8); plot(ica(4,:));
title('8')
```

The output plot I get is:

[image]

The first row of plots are the original signals. The second row are the recovered signals after they were mixed with a random matrix A

My question is: How do I modify the code above to specify different nonlinearity settings?

If you look at line 51 in [fastica.m](https://github.com/probml/pmtksupport/blob/master/fastICA-2.5/fastica.m), there are 4 different options:

```
'pow3' (default)   g(u)=u^3
'tanh'             g(u)=tanh(a1*u)
'gauss             g(u)=u*exp(-a2*u^2/2)
'skew'             g(u)=u^2
```

I tried to do:

```
g='tanh'
```

and then I re-ran my code above, but it did not look like anything changed (got the same plots).

Then I tried to do:

```
g='gauss'
```

Again, same plots.

Would appreciate any help / feedback from the MATLAB community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be better if you overlapped both results, I was not able to differentiate between the two results without holding on one of them,

check the following for both 'pow3' and 'gauss',

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**EDIT**

Code used,

```
% change g in fastica (line 247) g='pow3'
N=500; %data size
v=[0:N-1];
sig(1,:)=sin(v/2); %sinusoid
sig(2,:)=((rem(v,23)-11)/9).^5; %funny curve
sig(3,:)=((rem(v,27)-13)/9); %saw-tooth
sig(4,:)=((rand(1,N)<.5)*2-1).*log(rand(1,N)); %impulsive noise
%create mixtures
Aorig=rand(size(sig,1));
mixedsig=(Aorig*sig);
%preform ica to unmix signal
ica = fastica(mixedsig);
figure(1)
plot(ica(3,:));
title('5')
figure(2)
plot(ica(1,:));
title('6')
figure(3)
plot(ica(2,:));
title('7')
figure(4)
plot(ica(4,:));
title('8')




% Change g in fastica (line 247),  g= 'gauss';

ica = fastica(mixedsig);

figure(1)
hold on
plot(ica(3,:),'r:');
figure(2)
hold on
plot(ica(1,:),'r:');
figure(3)
hold on
plot(ica(2,:),'r:');
figure(4)
hold on
plot(ica(4,:),'r:');
```

Comment: could you please show the code for setting the nonlinear parameter?